# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, intent

O meu logcat está acusando um erro de ponteiro para iniciar a atividade `Ouvir` estou vendo mas não achei o erro.
Saindo essas mensagens quando eu executo a aplicação:

```
11-27 22:09:40.631: E/AndroidRuntime(1513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rs.player/com.rs.player.Ouvir}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Método que chama a `Activity` através do `Intent` por meio de um `MenuItem` na classe principal `MainActivity`:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_1:
                // Esta é a classe que está acusando o erro: 
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ouvir.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

No `AndroidManifest` a atividade está sendo aplicada:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rs.player"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
         >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
                    android:label="@string/app_name" 
                    android:name=".Ouvir" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" class=".Ouvir" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: O código quebra quando voce instancia o Intent?

Comment: O método `onOptionsItemSelected` está dentro de uma Activity?

Comment: Eu resolvi trocando o nome do método e substituindo o seu javadoc.

Comment: estou com problemas agora no reiniciar o áudio o logcat avisa que está com problema de salvar o buffer em um local específico: `11-28 13:29:44.841: E/com.rs.player.StreamingMediaPlayer(888): Buffered File path: /data/data/com.rs.player/cache/playingMedia0.dat`